# initializing a property inside a constructor when deserializing

Tags: c#, xml, constructor, deserialization, xsd2code

I use Xsd2Code to generate classes. However one of the classes causes me a problem with its constructor, because of the loop and throws StackOverflowException.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xsd2Code", "3.4.0.32990")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = true)]
public partial class ApproverType : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ApproverType replacesField;

    public ApproverType()
    {
        this.replacesField = new ApproverType();
    }

    public ApproverType Replaces
    {
        get
        {
            return this.replacesField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this.replacesField != null))
            {
                if ((replacesField.Equals(value) != true))
                {
                    this.replacesField = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("Replaces");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.replacesField = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Replaces");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's an infinite loop

Comment: Yes it will you have created an infinite recursive loop, when the constructor is called it calls itself because it creates another instance of of the class and assigns it to replacesField, which continues until you blow the stack.

Comment: How to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Remove this.replacesField = new ApproverType(); from constructor

Comment: posted an update with workaround using a collection of single item

Answer (score 1):

How is the `Replaces` property diclared in your XSD? Probably it's a required element, and the tool generates an instance to comply with the contract.

You could then try to change the definition, making it optional.

If it's something like:

```
<xs:element name="Replaces" type="ApproverType" use="required" />
```

You then have to change it to:

```
<xs:element name="Replaces" type="ApproverType" use="optional" />
```

EDIT:
A scheme would be incorrect anyway, because a recursive required element is impossible in xml too:

```
<ApproverType>
 <Replaces>
   <Replaces>
     <Replaces>
       <Replaces>
        ... infinite
 <Replaces>
 <OtherProperty />
<ApproverType>
```

EDIT:

One possible workaround would be having a backing property as a collection of single element:

```
public List<ApproverType> ReplacesWorkaround { ... }
```

in another part of partial class:

```
public ApproverType Replaces
{
 get
 {
  return ReplacesWorkaround.SingleOrDefault();
 }
 set
 {
  ReplacesWorkaround.RemoveAll();
  ReplacesWorkaround.Add(value);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there are other classes like this.. Obviously this tool is somehow buggy. https://xsd2code.codeplex.com/workitem/7419

I am using version 3.4.0.32990. Is there a way to fix this, easily

Comment: you should be updating original question instead of answering your own question with another quesion